# How can I repair this wood window trim?

Tags: wood, windows, frame

A small section of the window frame has rotted away (either that, or a woodpecker went at it)

Here is a picture of it

[image]
[image]
<sup>*Click for larger view*</sup>

What is the best way to fix this? Can I just cut out part of the broken piece and insert it in? I don't know how that piece is held in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see damage to sill (under window), brick mold (covers/protects L/R window edge).  Not shown but certainly contributing is the flashing/dripedge/overhang ABOVE window.

If rot extends through sill and there wasn't proper waterproofing UNDER the sill and above the basic framing, your wall below the window is at risk.

This looks like a replacement window job that didn't address water-shedding/building integration.

As such, a replacement window is relatively easily removed.  Replacement wood and the rot issues can dealt with much easier.  Then waterproofing can be integrated below, on sides and above.

[This JLC article](http://www.jlconline.com/coastal-contractor/replacing-windows-in-brick-veneer-homes.aspx) deals with replacement windows in brick, flashing and water management.

Answer (score 0):

Remove wood trim.

Add foam insulation. (Moisture may have caused the movement you're seeing)

Install trim.

Caulk. (I suggest 100% silicone if you don't care if the caulk is white. I always suggest exterior caulk for around Windows. If you want to paint after, use any OSI product)